# wget command on 32 bit jre not working

Tags: java, wget

My WGET Command is not working under my 32BIT JRE, but on the 64BIT Version it is running just fine. Any ideas?

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "wget": CreateProcess error=2, cannot find file

String command = "wget --quiet -O \""+props.getProperty("xmlFolder")+""+rs.getString("software")+".xml\" \"ftp://"+props.getProperty("ftpUser")+":"+props.getProperty("ftpPasswort")+"@"+rs.getString("xmlPfad")+"\"";

              System.out.println(command); 
              Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

              p.waitFor();
```

Comment: It says `CreateProcess error=2, cannot find file`.  Does that give you a hint?

Comment: not at all, because when i switch my JRE in netbeans to 64bit, it works fine.

Comment: and i know that the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to execute processes in java with a single string and quoting.  separate each parameter into a separate java string and use the `exec(String[])` method.

then, figure out why `wget` is not in the PATH and either add it to the PATH or use a absolute path to the executable.

Comment: ok i will try it. but when i copy the command into my command line it just works fine. it is not working in my netbeans programm.